# Doing multiple actions in a for loop

Tags: python, xlrd

I am trying to write a small script to essentially check various IP addresses listed in an excel spreadsheet, and reference them with hostnames listed in the same excel spreadsheet. I have all of the ground work layed out but there are a lot of inconsistencies and things in my code I think I could do better.

The 2 main problems I am having right now is that when I add in my if - else statements, all of the code breaks and the for loop tries to use the entire list as the input instead of doing a item in the list. The other problem is that the output of the gethostbyaddr, when it does work, comes out with the domain at the end leading to the hostnames not being exactly in the excel spreadsheet as it appears in python.

```
#Import Libraries Nessisary for NSLookup and Excel
import socket
import xlrd

#Declare The Excel File to be Used at Runtime by User Input
input_file = input("Enter the full address of the spreadsheet to be used: ")
excel_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(input_file)

#Declare The Sheet to be Used at Runtime by User Input and convert sheet number into "Index Value"
input_sheet = int(input("Enter the sheet number you would like to select (1,2,3, etc...): "))
input_sheet = input_sheet - 1
excel_sheet = excel_workbook.sheet_by_index(input_sheet)

#Declare the First Column (Skip Header) as Hostname list to be used
excel_hostname = excel_sheet.col_values(0, start_rowx=1, end_rowx=None)
#Declare the Second Column (Skip Header) as ip address list to be used
excel_ip_address = excel_sheet.col_values(1, start_rowx=1, end_rowx=None)

#Create a For Loop consisting of every ip address in the Excel Spreadsheet
for i,ip in enumerate(excel_ip_address):
    try:
        #Use an Equivelant NSLookup Command to Check the Current Spreadsheet Index ip for Hostname
        nslookup = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)[0]
        #Use If - Else Statement to check for Excel Spreadsheet Inconsistencies
        if nslookup == excel_hostname:
            #If First NSLookup Matches Excel Spreadsheet, re-run to now Check for Multiple Entries
            nslookup2 = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)[0]
            #Use Second If - Else Statement to check for Multiple DNS Entries
            if nslookup == nslookup2:
                #If Second NSLookup Matches Excel Spreadsheet, re-run to now Check for Multiple Entries One Last Time
                nslookup3 = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)[0]
                #Use Third If - Else Statement to check for Multiple DNS Entries One Last Time
                if nslookup == nslookup3:
                    #If all Checks Have Been Passed, Proceed to the Next ip with a Message that this ip is ok
                    print(ip, "No Anomalies Detected")
                #Third If - Else Statement - Third Try to Resolve a Different Hostname in Case the First Two Times Brought the Same Result
                else:
                    print(ip, "-- Multiple DNS Entries Detected --",      "Spreadsheet DNS is --", excel_hostname, "Second DNS Entry is --", nslookup3)
            #Second If - Else Statement - If Hostname Matches the First If Statement but Changes the Second Time it Means there are Multiple DNS Entries 
            else:
                print(ip, "-- Multiple DNS Entries Detected --", "Spreadsheet DNS is --", excel_hostname, "Second DNS Entry is --", nslookup2)
        #First If - Else Statement - If Hostname does not Match Spreadsheet on First try, must mean spreadsheet inconsistencies
        else:
            print(excel_ip_address, "-- Hostname does not match Excel Spreadsheet --", "Spreadsheet --", excel_hostname, "NSLookup --", nslookup)
    #Use a Try - Except to Catch any possible errors Such as Unreachable Host
    except socket.error:
        print(ip, "An Error Occured with this Address")
```

Comment: You're making a classic mistake when searching a list. Just because one element in the list doesn't match the hostname, it doesn't mean that the hostname isn't found, it may be found in another list element.

Comment: Both your `socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)[0]` calls should return the same thing. Why are you doing it twice?

Comment: `excel_hostname` is a list of hostnames, not a single hostname. You should be using `if nslookup in excel_hostname:`

Comment: If you just want the first part of the DNS name, use `socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)[0].split('.')[0]`

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for the help. The only thing I need right now (at least I think) is how am I able to have the loop continue with extra steps (The If - Else statements). As it stands if I try to run the script with a single ip address in my excel file it works, while if I have more than 1 it combines all of the ip addresses into a single list and tries to run it through the commands more than once

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do with all those extra `if/else` statements. They're all doing the same thing.

Comment: Please add a sample of the spreadsheet and the desired result.

Comment: If the IP resolves to multiple names, are you trying to check if any of them are in the spreadsheet? Then don't select just `[0]`. You can use `if any(name in excel_hostname for name in socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)):`

Comment: What I am trying to do is take a spreadsheet which has column A as hostnames, and column B as ip addresses, and make sure that the one ip address in B matches the one hostname in A. If the hostname does not match then that should throw a messgae, and if the hostname matches but there are other hostnames associated with that ip address, that also should throw a message

Comment: So use the `any()` expression above to check if it matches. Then check if the length of the list of hostnames is longer than 1 to tell if there are other hostnames. I suggest you put the result of `gethostbyaddr()` in a variable so you can perform multiple checks.

Comment: Ok great and do you know if there is a way to get the gethostbyaddr()[1] format which is the alias' to be in the same format you mentioned above (.split('.')[0]). That method only works for the single hostname option ([0])

Comment: Also how do I get the For Loop to do all of these If - Else statements per item in my list. With the code shown out in my post, when I use If - Else Statements with multiple entries in my list, the script treats all of the list inputs as a single entry to run through

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over the rows of the spreadsheet, there's no need to extract them as separate lists.

```
for rownum in range(1, excel_sheet.nrows)
    hostname, ip = excel_sheet.row_values(rownum, 0, 1)
    nslookup = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)
    # remove domain suffixes
    nslookup = [name.split('.')[0] for name in nslookup]
    if any(name == hostname for name in nslookup):
        print("f{hostname} matches {ip}")
        if len(nslookup) > 1:
            print(f" but has extra names")
    else:
        print("f{hostname} doesn't match {ip}")
```